# I need to get emails with help of EWS in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using MailListClient.MailListServiceReference;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace MailListClient
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var service = GetBinding();

           ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

           try
           {
               FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
                   WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
                   new ItemView(10));

               foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
                   Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
               Console.ReadLine();
           }
       }

       static ExchangeService GetBinding()
       {
           ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
           service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("zxzxzxzxzx@email.com", "password");
           try
           {
               service.Url = new Uri("https://email.com/AutoDiscover/AutoDiscover.xml");
           }
           catch (AutodiscoverRemoteException ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown: " + ex.Error.Message);
           }
           return service;
       }
   }
}
```

But I get Exception: **The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.**
What is the problem?

Comment: At what point are you getting the Exception thrown?  What happens when you're stepping through the code?

Comment: I get it at this row `FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL may be wrong. Here is the URL format I am using in code which is definitely working in a few applications (2007 and 2010):

```
https://[fully qualified domain name]/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

The rest of your code looks correct at a cursory level.

Comment: It's the same exception even if I change to `https://email.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx` :/

Comment: @anlean - Are you literally trying to use email.com or just using that as an example domain? Because if you go to that link, you will see it's a 404 error page thrown by an Apache server which seems unlikely to be hosting EWS.

Comment: email is not fake but I registered it to test if EWS is working because I need to get a "real" email, pars it and then send it to another server/system/modul. Is there some email providers which have EWS running? Or how can I do it locally?

Comment: @anleon - I don't a vendor who offers EWS as a consumable service (not to say that there aren't vendors out there). I'd recommend seeing if Microsoft offers what you are looking for.

Setting it up locally gives you complete control over the configuration but it does require an Active Directory environment with a domain controller and Exchange server (and appropriate licensing). If you have access to such an environment, it's definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Because the file you are requesting does not exist. I know that sounds purely antagonistic, but it's the simplest answer.

Follow this procedure as needed:

1. Get out Fiddler2 and trace the request. Is it going where you think it should be going?
2. Make sure you haven't spelt anything wrong.
3. Refer to the docs your IT support has given you
4. Go to your IT with the url and ask why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

For EWS this is triggered by an alias being used to override SMTP headers.

Check the mail properties of an address for it's SMTP address and any aliases, the alias will have priority.